# Grid action column getter not getting my field

Tags: adminhtml, grid, magento-1

My action column 'getter' is not getting the field 'meter_id' that I need. (Magento 1.9)  Here is my code:

```
    $link= $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
        'id'        => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'),
        'key'       => $this->getRequest()->getParam('key'),
        'action'    => 'delete'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('action_delete', array(
        'index'     => 'meter_id',
        'getter'    => 'getMeterId',
        'header'    => 'Action',
        'width'     => 15,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'filter'    => false,
        'type'      => 'action',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'url'     => $link,
                'caption' => 'Delete',
                'field'   => 'meter_id'
            ),
        )
    ));
```

Results in this url when clicked:

```
http://127.0.0.1/... .../edit/id/1/key/82a03e3076236b17dc32c6eb2ea53601/action/delete/
```

I need the 'meter_id' field key in the url too and don't understand my error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the getURL method does not work together with the getter and field.  The getter works perfectly once getURL was removed and the link restructured as follows:

```
    $link = array(
        'base'      => '*/*/edit' .
        '/id/' . $this->getRequest()->getParam('id') .
        '/action/' . 'delete');

    $this->addColumn('action_delete', array(
        // 'index'      => 'meter_id',
        'getter'    => 'getMeterId',
        'header'    => 'Action',
        'width'     => 15,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'filter'    => false,
        'type'      => 'action',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'url'     => $link,
                'caption' => 'Delete',
                'field'   => 'meter_id'
            ),
        )
    ));
```

resulting URL with desired query string:

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/... .../edit/id/1/action/delete/meter_id/1/key/82a03e3076236b17dc32c6eb2ea53601/
```

I hope this helps you too!