# My javascript doesn't run in a custom magento1.9 module

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, javascript, grid, select

I try to use javascript for a dropdown list I've implemented into a grid as shown in the image.

[image]

The renderer I use for this dropdown list is like

```
<?php

class Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Category extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{   
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $category = Mage::getModel('thorleif/category')->getCollection();
        $category_rows = $category->getData();

        $html = '<select id="select_category" name="select_category">';
        $sep = '';
        foreach ($category_rows as $rows) {
            // put the correct key here
            if (!$rows['level']) {
                $html .= $sep . "<optgroup label='{$rows['name']}'>";
                $sep = '</optgroup>';
            } else {
                $nbsp = str_repeat('&nbsp;', ($rows['level'] - 1)* 5);
                $html .= "<option value='{$rows['id_linio_category']}' title='{$rows['name']}'>
                $nbsp {$rows['name']}</option>";
            }
        }
        $html .= '</select>';

        return $html;
    }
}
?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script>
    var data = $( "#select_category option:selected" ).text();
    console.log(data);
</script>
```

and the Grid code is

```
<?php
...
$this->addColumn('linio',
    array(
        'header' => 'Linio Category',
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'linio',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'renderer' => 'Ns_Thorleif_Block_Adminhtml_Commerciaux_Edit_Form_Renderer_Category'
    )
);

$this->addColumn('action',
    array(
        'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
        'width'     => '100',
        'type'      => 'action',
        'getter'    => 'getId',
        'actions'   => array(
            array(
                'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Sync'),
                'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/sync'),
                'field'     => 'id',
                'target'=>'_blank'
            )
        ),
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'index'     => 'stores',
        'is_system' => true,
    )
);

return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

So I try to get the value/text of the dropdown selected value, but I cannot do this maybe the way to do it is different that the other CMS.
My Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <routeuradmin_adminhtml_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="thorleif/adminhtml_commerciaux" name="blocktest" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/javascript</rel><href>https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js</href></action>
        </reference>
    </routeuradmin_adminhtml_index_index>
</layout>
```

Any Idea or suggestion to implement or get those values please?

Comment: Have you some error in console and did you find well the `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"` in your code source ?

Comment: no, when the srcipt is ubicated in the renderer file nothing happens. but when I put it in the grid file I find this error `TypeError: element.attachEvent is not a function.  prototype.js:5653:9
TypeError: elementClassName is undefined` and custom module stop charging

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution for you problem?

Comment: Sorry I was busy. Yes I can show the text chosen dropdownlist value in console with plain javascript without using the last part where you mentioned `$row->getId`. I've tried to get the value number and not the text with `.val()`. Sorry I'm not strong on javascript, if I want to post the gotten id value how could I post it with the **Sync action**?

Comment: "Sync Action"? ... Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your js like this:

```
<layout>
    <your_layout_handle> <!-- adminhtml_dashboard_index for exemple-->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/javascript</rel><href>https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js</href></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_dashboard_index>
</layout>
```

**EDIT:**

I think that you dont get the selected option ! try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select#select_category').ready(function() {
            var selectedText = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            alert(selectedText);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added to my existing layout as in my edit post. but nothing still happend. when I remove the script tag for the javascript url in the renderer file, the last script code become displayed as an "echo" before the grid

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: I've tried again but still same problem (as in the picture updated) when I don't put this part `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>` . and with it nothing happens.

Comment: This mean that the js lib is not present in your page, you can check it in the source code, well let `src="..jquery-1.12.3.js"`in your page ans try my code, check also if you get well the value option !

Comment: ok, let me do some test and will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

Either add your javascript code to `$html` variable or you put in a seperate file and load it via

```
<layout>
    <your_grid_layout_handle>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <script>your-script.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </your_grid_layout_handle>
</layout>
```

---

If you don't need jQuery for other things I would use plain javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        elem = document.getElementById('select_category');
        if (elem.selectedIndex != -1) {
            console.log(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].text);
        }
    });
</script>
```

For logging `onchange` value you can replace

```
$html = '<select id="select_category" name="select_category">';
```

with

```
$html = '<select id="select_category" name="select_category" onchange="console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)>';
```

---

If you use `$html = '<select id="select_category" name="select_category">';` in `render()` method, you'll get invalid HTML, because an element ID should be unique at a page, but you'll get `id="select_category"` for every row.

Think this should be replaced with

```
$elem = 'select_category' . $row->getId();
$html = '<select id="' . $elem . '" name="' . $elem . '">';
```

---

**Edit:**

> if I want to post the gotten id value how could I post it with the Sync action? – javaTodev

Is this what you'trying to achieve?

```
$this->addColumn('linio',
    array(
        'header'    => 'Linio Category',
        'align'     => 'left',
        'index'     => 'linio',
        'filter'    => false,
        'sortable'  => false,
        'type'      => 'options',
        'options'   => Mage::getModel('thorleif/category')->getOptionsArray()
    )
);
```

Add this to `Ns_Thorleif_Model_Category`

```
public function getOptionsArray()
{
    $options = array();
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $option) {
        $options[$option->getIdLinioCategory()] = $option->getName();
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Is not clear that you want to implement above. But I'm trying like this way `<script type="text/javascript">
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {
        elem = document.getElementById('select_category');
        if (elem.selectedIndex != -1) {
   var val = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
   window.location.href = '*/*/sync?val=' + val;
            //window.document.write(val);
   console.log(elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value);
        }
    });
</script>` and to get the value in the syncAction using $_GET['val'] I can get it but front still executing.

Comment: Not sure if i got it right ... you want to set a value in your dropdown and with hitting "sync" it should be passed to your controller action? If yes, the updated code should work. Dropdown value should be passed there ...

Comment: I have the grid with dropdown list. First I have to chose a value from the dropdown list then I have to click on sync (the action is actualy generate an xml with some details I get from database) and the xml should contain also the dropdown chosed value. So it will work with added code you sent me? I've tried also to save the value in a table que get it in sync action directly from database. I didn't understand this `Ns_Thorleif_Model_Category` is it my file Category or is it a new file that I should create?Thanks again

Comment: Add this method to `Ns_Thorleif_Model_Category` ... its there to generate the dropdown. Think this code should work for you.

Comment: I've tried yesterday but the column goes empty. if you have a way to share my screen with you let me know please. in Model I use different way to get list names from database. the dropdown I have it already generated. My blocker is more get the value when a sync action is called.

Comment: Or in another way, how could I save the selected value in dropdown list to a table in database?

Comment: @javaTodev there was a typo in .... replace `'type'      => 'options',` with `'type'      => 'select',`, then a dropdown should be rendered and with hitting "sync" the value should be passed to your controllers "syncAction".

Comment: You're absolutly right. I change options by select and I get my category list, I found in some posts that we cannot use select into AddColumn but it seems to work. Know how can I get the id value of the selected name in the dropdown list?

Comment: Have you tried `getParam('linio')`? It should give you the ID of your category.

Comment: I've tried with `$this->getRequest()->getParam('linio')` but it returns NULL. I've printed the Params and I get only the row id for magento grid and the session Key, nothing else. I don't know if there's a way to send it with action sync in controllers as another params.

Comment: I think I have to find a form to send this Param with the grid action, in the way to use two Params getId and getLinioId something [like] https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98394/grid-action-column-getter-not-getting-my-field but it will be a challenge get also the selected value before to send it. Sometimes I've seen that they use 'onclick' into the action I've tried with onchange but without result. The unic way when I get (but only the default selected Id) is when the webpage is refreshed like two times.

Comment: @javaTodev could you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've put the dropdown list out of the grid as a fieldset into a form and I will save the value I need to use for my process and then get it from DB. It's work for me like this without to add any javascript. I know that is not the solution for the issue posted but this is another way to resolve my blocker.
[image: My solution]